# Prepopulate a standard field for Contacts

Tags: contact, standard-objects

This is my simple use case. I search for a Contact, if the search does not yield results I give the option of creating a new Contact. On clicking it, create a new Contact page is shown.
Now here is the problem, I want to prepopulate the Account Name field. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom Visualforce page for adding a new Contact and override the new button for contact. This Visualforce page can pre-populate the Account Name field